# COM+ application can't be changed

Tags: com, com+

I was updating a COM+ application, when an error showed up, saying that it couldn't be changed.  Now, whenever I go into properties on one of the components in that application, or the properties for that application, everything is greyed out, not allowing me to change it.  Delete is no an option for the application, and if I hit delete on the component, it tells me "Some changes could not be applied due to the following errors:" - "The selected item cannot be changed.  The item is currently locked against changes."  I can't seem to find anything on google.  At one point there was an HRESULT that showed up, I don't remember exactly what it was, but it turned out to be something like COM_ADMIN_E_NOT_CHANGEABLE, which also didn't give me much from google.

Logged on as domain user with admin privileges.
Running windows server 2008 standard.

Comment: Erm, check it out from source control first?

Comment: You want me to... check out a COM+ application... from... source control...

Comment: Do you have any familiarity with COM+?  If I can make my question clearer, please let me know.  If you have no familiarity, please don't downvote me because you don't know what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Protection (Disable deletion and/or Disable changes) enabled for the COM+ Application?  Check by looking at Properties->Advanced for the Application:

[image: Advanced Tab]

If so then un-check Disable deletion and/or Disable changes and click OK.  You should now be able to make changes/delete the application.

Comment: Unfortunately even that page cannot be udpated.

Comment: @Kyle: what OS are you running? Are Disable deletion and Disable changes checked but grayed out? What account are you logged on with?

Comment: Logged on as domain user with admin privileges.  The boxes are not checked.  Running windows server 2008 standard.

Answer (score 0):

Going off what Lucas had said, it will work if you do a .\Administrator, and edit the properties.

The important thing to note here is under the Properties of the COM Object, the **Activation** tab will be the focus. Try selecting **Server Application** here. Then under the **Security** tab, choose **Authentication** Level to **Packet**, and impersonation Level to **Impersonate**.

This should allow you to change anything you want now.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the answer was simple. Login as the local admin. ".\Administrator" then I had no problem bringing up the property pages for the COM+ applications.

Comment: Why the downvote? I had the exact same symptoms and resolved the issue by logging in as a local admin. I'm sure this will be helpful for someone.